# Converting a data table to nested object

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a table like

```
 
------------------
StudentId Name Subject Description
1     ABC   CA     Descr CA  
2     ABC   FM     Descr FM
3     ABC   MJ     Descr MJ 
4     ABC   DM     Descr DM
------------------
```

I have converted  the data table to anonymous objects first

```
var studentPlain= from dr in tbl.AsEnumerable()
      select new{
      StudentId =Convert.ToInt32(dr["StudentId"]),
      Name=Convert.ToString(dr["Name"]),
      Subject =Convert.ToString(dr["Subject"]),
      Description = Convert.ToString(dr["Description"])
      } 

class subj
{
public string Subject {get;set;}
public string Description {get;set;}
}
class student
{
public int StudentId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public List<subj> subjects{get;set;}
}
```

I need to convert it to student object

Comment: Please follow the How to Ask guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question in order to have better chances of receiving an adequate answer.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to add some more content to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This is not for DB but you will correct easily:

```
public class dbStudent
{
    public int StudentId;
    public string Name;
    public string Subject;
    public string Description;
}

public class subject
{
    public string Subject;
    public string Description;
}

public class student
{
    public int StudentId;
    public string Name;
    public List<subject> subjects;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbStudebts = new List<dbStudent>();
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { StudentId = 1, Name = "Bob", Subject = "Math", Description = "High math" });
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { StudentId = 1, Name = "Bob", Subject = "Geography", Description = "Mountains" });
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { StudentId = 2, Name = "John", Subject = "Philosophy", Description = "Philosophy of life" });

        var result = (from o in dbStudebts
                      group o by new { o.StudentId, o.Name } into grouped
                      select new student()
                      {
                          StudentId = grouped.Key.StudentId,
                          Name = grouped.Key.Name,
                          subjects = grouped.Select(c => new subject()
                          {
                              Subject = c.Subject,
                              Description = c.Description
                          }).ToList()
                      }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Wouldn't it take so much time to group by name as well? 
Since I could have done based on StudentId only. I am concerned a little about performance.  If I have 15 fields in Student Class then it will hamper performance

I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: For 15 fields I don't know, you need to check both scenarious

Comment: @AjaySuwalka, But I think it would be the same, because you are selecting plain list and operate then in memory not in database.

Comment: It consumes CPU as well for processing, I can ignore RAM consumption anyways, since memory it going to be released as the scope goes out.